# Configure tags to ignore noop file

Tags: ctags

Wordpress has an annoying [noop file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214456/why-does-wordpress-have-a-noop-php-file) which `ctags` thinks defines all Wordpress functions.

```
/**
 * @ignore
 */
function add_action() {}

/**
 * @ignore
 */
function did_action() {}

/**
 * @ignore
 */
function do_action_ref_array() {}
```

**How can I tell `ctags` to ignore this file when it creates the tag list?** I cannot simply delete the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a terminal emulator.
2. At the prompt, type this command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open ctag's documentation:

   ```
   $ man ctags
   ```
3. Type this command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump to the first occurrence of the word `ignore`:

   ```
   /ignore
   ```
4. Press <kbd>n</kbd> a few times until you find a relevant section.
5. If you don't, try again with a synonym. Maybe… `exclude`:

   ```
   /exclude
   ```

Comment: Your answers are always poignant and address the real problem! In fact, `exclude` was the keyword that I needed. I _did_ search for `ignore` and for `file` as well before posting, but I did not go for the synonyms. **Thank you for teaching me to fish, and not simply throwing me fishes!**